# multiple listview in one activity

Tags: android, android-listview

Sorry if I can not speak good English,
how have multiple Listview in one activity that extends ListActivity such as

```
private List<Tour> tours;
ArrayAdapter<Tour> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tour>(this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tours);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

this code is for one Listview in activity that Listview's id is @android:id/list but i have two or more Lisview in one activity
Please guide me

Comment: then you should not extend ListActivity instead extend it as normal activity and give each listview's unique Id

Comment: ListActivity is specifically for One Single Activity. If you want more than one Listview in an activity. You should just extend Activity class and create multiple listivew.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to display 2 listviews in one activity one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extends `Activity` instead of `ListActivity` in your code.
And in your activity's layout xml file you should take two different id for that two list view.

See below reference links for more details...

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/02/a-simple-layout-with-two-listviews/

[Multiple Listviews in single Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577021/multiple-listviews-in-single-activity-in-android)

[Android how to display 2 listviews in one activity one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ListFragment instead ListActivity.

First Fragment:

```
public class FirstListFragment extends ListFragment {

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    private List<Tour> tours;
    ArrayAdapter<Tour> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tour>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tours);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // do something with the data
  }
}
```

Second fragment:

```
public class SecondListFragment extends ListFragment {

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    private List<Tour> tours;
    ArrayAdapter<Tour> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tour>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tours);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // do something with the data
  }
}
```

Now you should add fragments to layout in xml file of activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment android:name="com.your_package.FirstListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.your_package.SecondListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you find mor here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: give an error(The constructor ArrayAdapter<Tour>(MainActivity, int, List<Tour>) is undefined)

Comment: ArrayAdapter<Tour> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tour>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tours); Instead "this" use getActivity() because Fragment object is not child of Context.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your class with simple **Activity** and add multiple ListViews in it.